# SQLAlchemy looses column label on chained union/except_

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a somewhat complex query where I need to join subquery. That subquery contains except and union. In RAW sql it looks something like this

```
SELECT ... FROM table t
  JOIN (SELECT id AS foo_id FROM foo WHERE select_me
        EXCLUDE SELECT foo_id FROM bar WHERE add_or_remove = 'remove'
        UNION SELECT foo_id FROM bar WHERE add_or_remove = 'add') subq
    ON t.foo_id = subq.foo_id;
```

Where foo and bar tables are defined like this:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    select_me = Column(Boolean)


class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'

    foo_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    add_or_remove = Column(Enum('add', 'remove', name='add_or_remove'), primary_key=True)
```

When I'm trying to make this subquery in SQLAlchemy, it looses column label when I add second `union`/`except_`.

Here is what I'm talking about:

```
q = session.query(Foo.id.label('foo_id')).filter(Foo.select_me)
print(q.subquery().c)
```

Prints `['%(140275696626880 anon)s.foo_id']` still contains correct label

```
q = q.union(session.query(Bar.foo_id.label('foo_id')).filter(Bar.add_or_remove == 'add'))
print(q.subquery().c)
```

Prints `['%(140275696767384 anon)s.foo_id']` still contains correct label

```
q = q.except_(session.query(Bar.foo_id.label('foo_id')).filter(Bar.add_or_remove == 'remove'))
print(q.subquery().c)
```

Prints `['%(140275696769064 anon)s.%(140275696769008 anon)s_foo_id']` now column is labeled with autogenerated name and I cannot use it to specify condition in `join`.

For now I think I can just take first column and use it. But this is hacky solution, so I wonder if this is bug in SQLAlchemy or I'm doing something wrong.